# Error in ingest attachment plugin in ElasticSearch (NoClassDefFoundError)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to put data to ES using Logstash I get this error, I am using ingest_attachment plugin:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/james/mime4j/codec/DecodeMonitor
>           at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OutlookExtractor.decodeHeader(OutlookExtractor.java:349) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OutlookExtractor.normalizeHeaders(OutlookExtractor.java:315) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OutlookExtractor.parse(OutlookExtractor.java:140) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser.parse(OfficeParser.java:193) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser.parse(OfficeParser.java:130) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:120) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.tika.Tika.parseToString(Tika.java:568) ~[?:?]
>           at org.elasticsearch.ingest.attachment.TikaImpl$1.run(TikaImpl.java:94) ~[?:?]
>           at org.elasticsearch.ingest.attachment.TikaImpl$1.run(TikaImpl.java:91) ~[?:?]
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>           at org.elasticsearch.ingest.attachment.TikaImpl.parse(TikaImpl.java:91) ~[?:?]
>           at org.elasticsearch.ingest.attachment.AttachmentProcessor.execute(AttachmentProcessor.java:86) ~[?:?]
>           at org.elasticsearch.ingest.CompoundProcessor.execute(CompoundProcessor.java:100) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.ingest.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.java:58) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.ingest.PipelineExecutionService.innerExecute(PipelineExecutionService.java:166) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.ingest.PipelineExecutionService.access$000(PipelineExecutionService.java:41) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.ingest.PipelineExecutionService$2.doRun(PipelineExecutionService.java:88) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:596) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_121]
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.james.mime4j.codec.DecodeMonitor
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>           at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:814) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>           ... 23 more

**Formats that I am trying to index are:**

.URL
.a
.ans
.asc
.ascx
.asm
.asp
.aspx
.asx
.bas
.bat
.bcp
.c
.cc
.cls
.cmd
.cpp
.cs
.csa
.csproj
.css
.csv
.cxx
.dbs
.def
.dic
.doc
.docm
.docx
.dos
.dot
.dotx
.dsp
.dsw
.dwfx
.easmx
.edrwx
.eprtx
.ext
.faq
.fky
.h
.hhc
.hpp
.hta
.htm
.html
.htt
.htw
.htx
.hxx
.i
.ibq
.ics
.idl
.idq
.inc
.inf
.ini
.inl
.inx
.jav
.java
.jnt
.js
.jtx
.kci
.lgn
.log
.lst
.m3u
.mak
.mht
.mhtml
.mk
.msg
.obd
.obt
.odc
.odh
.odl
.odp
.ods
.odt
.one
.p7m
.pdf
.pkgdef
.pkgundef
.pl
.pot
.pps
.ppt
.pptm
.pptx
.prc
.rc
.rc2
.rct
.reg
.rgs
.rtf
.rul
.s
.scc
.shtm
.shtml
.snippet
.sol
.sor
.sql
.srf
.stm
.tab
.tdl
.tlh
.tli
.trg
.txt
.udf
.udt
.url
.user
.usr
.vb
.vbproj
.vbs
.vcproj
.vdw
.vdx
.viw
.vsct
.vsd
.vsdm
.vsdx
.vsixlangpack
.vsixmanifest
.vspscc
.vss
.vsscc
.vssm
.vssscc
.vssx
.vst
.vstm
.vstx
.vsx
.vtx
.wiq
.wri
.wtx
.xlb
.xlc
.xls
.xlsb
.xlsm
.xlsx
.xlt
.xml
.xps
.xsd
.xsl
.xslt
.zip

Comment: Maybe you should take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by adding jar file under elasticsearch lib folder.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadapachemime4jcore072jar.htm